# Wolfram says series is divergent, how is my proof wrong?

Tags: convergence-divergence, wolfram-alpha

Given the following series Wolfram Alpha says it diverges but when I was trying to prove it I came to the conclusion it converges and I can't figure out what's wrong.
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n+(-1)^n}$$

$$S_{2n+1}=\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{4}+ ... +\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n}$$

$$S_{2n+1}=-\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{20}-...-\frac{1}{2n(2n+1)}=-\sum\limits_{k=2}^{n} \frac{1}{2n(2n+1)} \to L$$

Where L is the sum of this clearly convergent series.

$$S_{2n+2}=S_{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+3} \to L$$
$$S_{n}\to L$$

So surely this must converge? I saw something similar used when proving the alternating series test but couldn't apply it on this series since $\frac{(-1)^n}{n+(-1)^n}$ isn't monotonous.

Edit: Seems like I must have messed up my input as I can't replicate the error on Wolfram. Thanks for the answers and sorry for wasting your time. Needed this result for something so got freaked out when it said it diverges the first time.

Comment: Can you post the link where does Wolfram say  it is divergent?

Comment: Seems Wolfram is in error.

Comment: @MathFail I tried to input it in Wolfram just now and it produced a number(so it's convergent). Not sure what went wrong the previous time. Perhaps my input was off (although I checked it a few times). But I can't seem to replicate this. Thanks for the answers everyone.

Comment: But entering "sum n=2..infinity (-1)^n/(n+(-1)^n)" gives the correct result (not putting in the limits gives the error).

Comment: Strange. Without specifying the limits WA interprets them correctly (2 to $\infty$), but says the sum diverges.